# How to change functional component's state from another component that is not a parent or a child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components, react-hooks

In my code I have a functional component that renders a list of the users in the database using a "load more" pagination, and a component that shows the details of a user alongside some actions when you click on them is the list, similarly to an file explorer. One of those actions is to delete the user. When you do so, the list of users doesn't update, and if you click the user you just deleted, an execution error will appear, for the code tries to use information from a null object. What is the best way to update the list component upon user deletion without using class components?

App.js - the parent of the list and detail components

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div id = "app">
    <div className = "section sectionTop">
      <Route path = "/" component = {BaseTop}/>
    </div>
    <div className = "Main">
      <div className = "section sectionMain sectionLeft">
      <Route path = "/" component = {BaseLeft}/>
      </div>
      <div className = "section sectionMain sectionCenter">
        <Route path = "/" exact component = {BaseCenter}/>
        <Route path = "/listusers" component = {UserList}/>
      </div>
      <div className = "section sectionMain sectionRight">
        <Route path = "/" exact component = {BaseRight}/>
        <Route path = "/adduser" component = {UserAdd}/>
        <Route path = "/listusers/:id" component = {UserInfo}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

UserList.js - the list of users

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState ([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState (0);

useEffect
(
    () =>
    {
        setPage (page+1);
    },
    []
);

useEffect
(
    () =>
    {
        try
        {
            const runEffect = async () =>
            {
                const response = await api.get
                (
                    `/users?page=${page}`
                );
                setUsers ([...users, ...response.data.docs]);
            }
            runEffect();
        }
        catch (error)
        {
            console.log (error);
        }
    },
    [page]
);

return (
    <div className = "userListArea">
        {
            users.map
            (
                (user, index) =>
                {
                    return (
                        <div key = {index} className = "user">
                            <Link key = {index} to = {`/listusers/${user._id}`}>
                                <button
                                className = "buttonUser"
                                key = {index}>
                                    {user.name}
                                </button>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            )
        }
        <button
        className = "buttonLoadMore"
        onClick = {() => setPage (page+1)}>
            Carregar mais
        </button>
    </div>
)
```

UserInfo.js - the details of an user

```
const [user, setUser] = useState ({});
const [_id, set_id] = useState ("");

useEffect
(
    () =>
    {
        if (user.hasOwnProperty ("_id") === false)
        {
            set_id (match.params.id);
        }
        else
        {
            if (user._id !== match.params.id)
            {
                set_id (match.params.id);
            }
        }
        const runEffect = async () =>
        {
            const response = await api.get
            (
                "/searchuser",
                {
                    params:
                    {
                        _id
                    }
                }
            )
            if (user.hasOwnProperty ("name") === false)
            {
                setUser (response.data);
            }
            else
            {
                if (user.name !== response.data.name)
                {
                    setUser (response.data);
                }
            }
        }
        runEffect();
    }
);

async function handleDeleteUser (_id)
{
    if (window.confirm(`Você realmente deseja remover o usuário ${user.name}?`))
    {
        const response = await api.delete
        (
            "/users",
            {
                params:
                    {
                        _id
                    }
            }
        );
        if (response.data._id === _id)
        {
            window.alert(`O usuário ${user.name} foi excluído.`);
        }
    }
}

return (
    <div className = "userInfoArea">
        <div className = "name">{user.name}</div>
        <div className = "email">{user.email}</div>
        <button className = "buttonEdit">Editar</button>
        <Link to = "/listusers">
            <button
            className = "buttonDelete"
            onClick = {() => handleDeleteUser (user._id)}
            >
                Excluir
            </button>
        </Link>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Hi there. The way you have laid out your router is very weird and can add a lot of complexity to your component heir-achy. Can you refactor it so that each route has a template with sections?

Comment: You cannot update the state of a component that is not a parent or a child without using an external state management solution, such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or the new [useContext hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Comment: @Redline thank you very much. The useContext hook did the trick just fine. In addition to using it in that case, I'll be able to use when storing the user that is currently logged in.

Comment: @DanielDuong I see. I'll organize my code in the way you have proposed. However, for now, Redline, has answered my question, and I don't think it is necessary for me to update the question. But, if, for any reason, you really wish to see the code organized, let me know and I'll update the question.

Comment: @Capeudinho Just posted an answer in case anyone else had the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update the state of a component that is not a parent or a child without using an external state management solution, such as [Redux](http://redux.js.org) or the new [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) api/hook. These libraries involve moving all individual component's states to a larger centralized global state, which can be updated and accessed by all components.